# error MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I want to embed my web application to server, in localhost there is no problem but when I put my application and run it there are several problems.

This is the problem

```
UPDATE HistoriKegiatan SET TglSelesaiPemberkasan = CURDATE(), WaktuSelesaiPemberkasan = CURTIME() WHERE IdHistori = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1
```

And this is my code

```
$idKegiatan = (int) $_GET['idkegiatan'];
$NmKegiatan = $_GET['nmkegiatan'];
$transferto = $_POST['transferto'];

$catatan = $_POST['catatan'];
$tim = $_SESSION['team'];
$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];

$sql = "SELECT Max(IdHistori) as LastHId FROM HistoriKegiatan WHERE IdHistori IN (Select IdHistori from HistoriKegiatan where idKegiatan = $idKegiatan)";

    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    $no = dbNumRows($result);
    $data = dbFetchAssoc($result);
    $lastHId = $data['LastHId'];


$sql = "UPDATE HistoriKegiatan SET TglSelesaiPemberkasan = CURDATE(), WaktuSelesaiPemberkasan = CURTIME() WHERE IdHistori = $lastHId ";
echo $sql;
dbQuery($sql);
```

anyone can help me to fix this problem? 
Sorry for my english

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Looks like `$lastHId` is not set

Comment: Please post your database schema - tables, columns etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT Max(IdHistori) as LastHId FROM HistoriKegiatan WHERE IdHistori IN (Select IdHistori from HistoriKegiatan where idKegiatan = '$idKegiatan')";
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE HistoriKegiatan SET TglSelesaiPemberkasan = CURDATE(), WaktuSelesaiPemberkasan = CURTIME() WHERE IdHistori = '$lastHId '";
```

its work for you

Comment: Non escaped double quotes in a double quoted string.  Just wrap `$idKegiatan` in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be: `WHERE IdHistori = '$lastHId'";`

```
$sql = "UPDATE HistoriKegiatan SET TglSelesaiPemberkasan = CURDATE(), WaktuSelesaiPemberkasan = CURTIME() WHERE IdHistori = '$lastHId'";
echo $sql;
```

Comment: It depends on what data type IdHistori is. If it is an integer you don't need it